# Salvar output após aplicar um replace

Tags: java, android, regex, stream

Olá, tenho o seguinte código abaixo, mas preciso aplicar um `replace` no `output`(`FileOutputStream`) pego via `http` antes de salva-lo.

```
    public void DownloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName) {
        new Thread(new Runnable()

        {
            public void run() {
        try {
            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/test.txt");

            //create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set up some things on the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();

            //set the path where we want to save the file
            //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            //sd card.
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"test.txt");

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                //downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();

//catch some possible errors...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                //faca qualquer coisa aqui
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

**No `output` tenho o seguinte:**

```
1
00:00:02,285 --> 00:00:05,277
<font color="#12E512">- Wow.</font>

2
00:00:07,390 --> 00:00:08,789
<i>Hello<i>
...
```

Preciso que seja aplicado um replace para as tags `<` e `>` mas excluindo o `-->` dessa regra, neste exemplo temos apenas a tag `<font color` mas é possível que exitam outras tags na formatação, como por exemplo `<i>`.

**O resultado final deve ser algo como isso:**

```
1
00:00:02,285 --> 00:00:05,277
[font color="#12E512"]- Wow.[/font]

2
00:00:07,390 --> 00:00:08,789
[i]Hello[i]
...
```

> Nota, ele deve fazer isso em todo o arquivo/output.

Comment: É, aparentemente tem alguns códigos que não são usados, me perdoem por isso, sintam-se livre para fazer os ajustes necessários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa expressão regular deve ajudar:

```
String html = ""// seu html...
String replaced = html.replaceAll("\\<(.+?)\\>(.+?)\\<(.+?)\\>", "[$1]$2[$3]");
```

**Segue o bloco completo, fazendo a conversões antes de escrever no outputstream:**

```
while ((bufferLength = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    // transforma o byte array em uma string unicode
    String bufferString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    // aplica a ereg modificando os tags
    bufferString = bufferString.replaceAll( 
     "\\<(.+?)\\>", "[$1]"); //(Atualização da regex correta)
    //escreve no stream de output convertendo a string pra um array de bytes 
    fileOutput.write(bufferString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")),
            0, bufferLength);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas como fazer isso com o `output`? Essa é a questão.

Comment: @Florida atualizei mostrando como fazer.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mas com um "bug" quando existe a quebra de linha ele não faz o replace. Ex: `<i>Primeira linha.`
`Segunda Linha.</i>` Funcionando apenas em uma unica linha Ex: `[i]Unica linha[/i]`

Comment: Isso corrige o "bug"  `"\\<(.+?)\\>", "[$1]"`, gastei algumas horas pra resolver isso, mas acredito que me ensinou algo.  A resposta é correta, não 100% =) **+1**

Comment: @Florida faça uma edição ajustando expressão regular que você utilizou, realmente nos exemplos que você passou não tinha esse cenário então acabei não tratando. Fico feliz que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Olá, fiz duas edições, foram rejeitadas, ao que parece eles não veem os comentários e fica difícil saber se é uma edição para melhorar ou não, então se possível, você mesmo poderia editar com a correção.